# calculations between continues subsequent groups

Tags: python, pandas

suppose we have the following `dataframe`

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'set_id': [0, 0,1,1,4,4,5,5,6,6],
                  'data': [-27, -45,-52,-65,-37, 20, 17, -45, -44, 15]})

    set_id  data
0   0       -27
1   0       -45
2   1       -52
3   1       -65
4   4       -37
5   4       20
6   5       17
7   5       -45
8   6       -44
9   6       15
```

I would like to perform a series of different calculations between pairs of subsequent sets, meaning I need to somehow 'extract' `dataframe`s with the `set_id`s
of (0,1), (4,5), (5,6) but not (1,4).

example of subsequent sequence `dataframe`

```
    set_id  data
0   0       -27
1   0       -45
2   1       -52
3   1       -65
```

---

I have created an additional column with `sequence_id` to then use [`groupby.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html#pandas-core-groupby-groupby-apply) on, however `set_id` 5 is in two different sequences so it's not a solution.

Any solutions? preferably a pandastic one.

Comment: `I would like to perform a series of different calculations`, please be more specific...

Comment: An example of one would be the ratio between the lengths of the subsequent sets or the ratio between the mean of the first set and first data value of the second set. however they are numerous and  I don't think they are really relevant to the nature of the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can generate values of groups with [`zip_longest`](https://docs.python.org/3.0/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest) with `fillvalue` parameter if unpair of unique values is added last previous value and then filter by [`Series.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html):

```
from  itertools import zip_longest

a = df['set_id'].unique()
b = [(x, y) for x, y in zip_longest(a[::2], a[1::2], fillvalue=a[-2])]
print (b)
[(0, 1), (4, 5), (6, 5)]

for x in b:
    df1 = df[df['set_id'].isin(x)]
    print (df1)

   set_id  data
0       0   -27
1       0   -45
2       1   -52
3       1   -65
   set_id  data
4       4   -37
5       4    20
6       5    17
7       5   -45
   set_id  data
6       5    17
7       5   -45
8       6   -44
9       6    15
```

Another idea is add last previous group (here 5) if unpair unique values:

```
df['g'] = pd.factorize(df['set_id'])[0] // 2

max_g = df.loc[df['g'] == df['g'].max(), 'set_id']
last_prev_df = df.loc[df['g'] == df['g'].max() - 1, 'set_id']


if max_g.nunique() == 1:
    df1 = df[df['g'] !=  df['g'].max()]
    df2 = df[df['set_id'] == last_prev_df.values[-1]].assign(g = df['g'].max())
    df3 = df[df['g'] ==  df['g'].max()]

    df = pd.concat([df1, df2, df3], ignore_index=False)
```

So possible groupby by helper column `g` and apply custom function:

```
def func(x):
    print (x)

df1 = df.groupby('g').apply(func)
   set_id  data  g
0       0   -27  0
1       0   -45  0
2       1   -52  0
3       1   -65  0
   set_id  data  g
4       4   -37  1
5       4    20  1
6       5    17  1
7       5   -45  1
   set_id  data  g
6       5    17  2
7       5   -45  2
8       6   -44  2
9       6    15  2
```

Answer (score 0):

you can get the list of parts of dataframe matching your condition like below

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'set_id': [0, 0,1,1,4,4,5,5,6,6],
                  'data': [-27, -45,-52,-65,-37, 20, 17, -45, -44, 15]})


id_sets = [(0,1), (4,5), (5,6)]
df_list = [df[np.in1d(df.set_id, id_set)] for id_set in id_sets]

for df in df_list:
    display(df)
```

**Output**

```
set_id  data
0   0   -27
1   0   -45
2   1   -52
3   1   -65

set_id  data
4   4   -37
5   4   20
6   5   17
7   5   -45

set_id  data
6   5   17
7   5   -45
8   6   -44
9   6   15
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get index pairs of subsequent set_id values, you may do something like this:

```
pairs = []
for r in df.itertuples():
    if r.set_id and r.set_id == last.set_id+1:
        pairs.append([last.Index, r.Index])
    last = r
```

*pairs* then contains list of index pairs *[[1, 2], [5, 6], [7, 8]]*

Or, to get sub-dataframes:

```
pairs = [df.loc[x:x+1] 
    for x in range(0, df.shape[0]-1) if df.loc[x, 'set_id']==df.loc[x+1, 'set_id']-1]
```

*pairs* then contains list of dataframes:

```
for s in pairs:
    print(s, type(s))

Output:
   set  data
1    0   -45
2    1   -52 <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
   set  data
5    4    20
6    5    17 <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
   set  data
7    5   -45
8    6   -44 <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
```